# Accept custom HttpHeaders for CORS requests in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, cors

I've an ExpressJS application exposing some data via REST. When I access the REST interface form the same origin or by using curl, everything is fine and my custom http header is forwareded to my route.

But when I try to access the REST interface from another origin my headers are removed.

The expressjs configuration looks like this

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept');

  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
};
app.all('/',allowCrossDomain);
app.get('/foo', function(req,res){
  console.dir(req.headers);
});
```

I try to access the api using the following JS code

```
var properties = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/foo?callback=?,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    headers: { "x-foo" : "FooBar"}
};
$.ajax(properties).done(onSuccess).fail(function(r, s, e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

On the server-side the custom header x-foo is not part of req.headers. If I use the following curl command my header exists

```
curl -H "x-foo: FooBar" -G http://localhost:3001/foo
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to find any solution to get this up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
app.all('/', ...);
```

does not do what you might think it does. It does **NOT** handle all incoming requests. It just handles all incoming requests for `/`, regardless of the verb being used. Hence, `all` means *all verbs*, not *all routes*. See its [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all) for details.

So, when you try to access `/foo` using the `$.ajax` call, your CORS middleware is not triggered. Perhaps this may be the reason. At least this could explain why it works from localhost and `curl`, but not from within the browser using a different domain.

Hope this helps.

PS: I'd recommend not to write your own CORS middleware, but use an existing one. I've made quite good experiences with [node-cors](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors).